# How to detect lost focus

Tags: google-glass

I am wondering, how do I detect that my LiveCard has lost focus or that the screen goes off because of no action from user?
I need to stop updating location on those events to save battery

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect when the screen goes off because your app will **exit** but you can detect when the program is closing. Your program closes when the screen goes off. The closing function runs when the screen goes off. I don't know if you are new to Android Development.

The **onStart** function is **called** when app opens and the **onStop** function is called when it is about to **close**. These are the **appropriate** places to **register** and **unregister**(stop) your events. You have to overwrite these two functions.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
   //you can register your Location event here
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
   //Un-Register your Location event here
    super.onStop();
}
```

EDIT:
If those two didnt work, try unregistring your sensor inside the onDestroy function instead. It should be called if the screen goes off because of no action in a short time.

```
  @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mLiveCard != null && mLiveCard.isPublished()) {    
            mLiveCard.unpublish();
            mLiveCard = null;
        }

        //Unregister your sensor below

        super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but are you sure that this is true for liveCards in glass? I am almost sure they don't exit.

Comment: I modified it and added onDestroy(). It should work. It works here. Did you try it? You can put Log.e("Destroyed "," from onDestroy"); inside the onDestroy function. Don't forget to put @Override at the top.